# Savon: How to change header from being <env:Header> to <soap:Header> or something different

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

In Savon, is there a way to change

```
<env:Header>
```

to be

```
<soap:Header>
```

or anything different?

I've tried in the request block putting an additional header tag like this:

```
soap.header['soap:Header']
```

But that won't work.

I've browsed [Savon Docs](http://savonrb.com/) and haven't found anywhere to change that tag, only by manually building the XML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EDITED for Savon 1.0.0

The value can be set in the configure block where you can also set logging and other parameters. Simply put

```
Savon.configure do |c|
  c.env_namespace = :soap
end
```

into your code.

Comment: I changed the answer for Savon 1.x

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions of Savon:

```
Savon.client(env_namespace: :soapenv)
```