# What is the difference between these two SOAP requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

I am sending a request to a SOAP API and unfortunately my knowledge of SOAP is limited. The following two requests both return a response but the response differs. The not working example returns a send_fax_response only. The working returns a send_fax_response and a send_fax_result. Any ideas as to why? Could it be the order?

### Not working

```
SOAP request: https://faxregistration.com/SfaxWS/SfaxAPI.asmx
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/sendFax", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, User-Agent: sfax-api gem 0.0.1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ins0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <ins0:sendFax>
      <ins0:xDoc>
        <FaxRequest>
          <DocMerge>false</DocMerge>
          <RecipientFax>555.123.4567</RecipientFax>
          <Password>test</Password>
          <UserId>test</UserId>
          <image>PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+VGVzdCBGYXg8L2JvZHk+PC9odG1sPg==</image>
          <DocType>html</DocType>
          <RecipientName>test</RecipientName>
        </FaxRequest>
      </ins0:xDoc>
    </ins0:sendFax>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

### Working

```
SOAP request: https://faxregistration.com/SfaxWS/SfaxAPI.asmx
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/sendFax", Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8, User-Agent: sfax-api gem 0.0.1
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <sendFax xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xDoc>
        <FaxRequest>
          <UserId>test</UserId>
          <Password>test</Password>
          <RecipientName>test</RecipientName>
          <RecipientFax>555.123.4567</RecipientFax>
          <DocType>html</DocType>
          <image>PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+VGVzdCBGYXg8L2JvZHk+PC9odG1sPg==</image>
          <DocMerge>false</DocMerge>
        </FaxRequest>
      </xDoc>
    </sendFax>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I notice is that the first line of your request is `env:Envelope` in the "Not Working" example and `soap:Envelope` in the "Working" example.

Aside from that, there's a couple of attributes that are also missing from this tag. They could be important, but I reckon it's the naming of that outer element which is causing the breakage.

Answer (score 1):

I think your soap server expects the the body, i.e., `<sendFax>` to have http://tempuri.org namespace defined within the element. If it is, changing body in the not_working soap request may also work.

```
<ins0:sendFax ins0:"http://tempuri.org/">
  <ins0:xDoc>
    <FaxRequest>
      <DocMerge>false</DocMerge>
      <RecipientFax>555.123.4567</RecipientFax>
      <Password>test</Password>
      <UserId>test</UserId>
      <image>PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+VGVzdCBGYXg8L2JvZHk+PC9odG1sPg==</image>
      <DocType>html</DocType>
      <RecipientName>test</RecipientName>
    </FaxRequest>
  </ins0:xDoc>
</ins0:sendFax>
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using Savon for Rails. My SOAP request always fails and I noticed that the working example is having **soap:Envelope** while my generated request has **env:Envelope**.
How can I make my **not-working** SOAP request into a **working** SOAP request?
Help please :)

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538757/savon-how-to-change-header-from-being-envheader-to-soapheader-or-something